# missing required extension: sapcoreaddon

Tags: installation, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to run install recipe sap_aom_som_b2b_b2c. However build was failed with following error.

```
Buildfile: C:\Hybris6\Hybris\bin\platform\build.xml
 [echo] C:\Hybris6\Hybris\bin\platform/tomcat/bin

BUILD FAILED
C:\Hybris6\Hybris\bin\platform\build.xml:18: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Hybris6\Hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\antmacros.xml:157: Missing required extensions: sapcoreaddon<-[yacceleratorstorefront],sappricingproductcarouseladdon<-[yacceleratorstorefront]. Please check your extension setup!
```

I am new to Hybris. Could you please help me if I am missing some step here?

Comment: Have you checked your extension setup?

Comment: It looks like this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hybrisconfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="resources/schemas/extensions.xsd">
 <extensions>
  <!--
    All extensions located in ${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/platform/ext are automatically loaded.
    More information about how to configure available extensions can be found here : https://wiki.hybris.com/x/nZVzC
  -->

  <path dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}" />


      
  <!-- ext-template -->
  <extension name="yempty" />
  <extension name="yhacext" />
 </extensions>
</hybrisconfig>

Comment: So have you looked up how to configure the extensions at *https://wiki.hybris.com/x/nZVzC* ?

Comment: Yes and it pretty much says that I can keep the file blank without specifying any extension and run installer for any recipe. While doing so I am getting above mentioned error

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed these steps?

1. Setup the hybris platform
   ./install.sh -r sap_aom_som_b2b_b2c
2. Initialize the hybris platform
   ./install.sh -r sap_aom_som_b2b_b2c initialize
3. Start the hybris server and datahub
   ./install.sh -r sap_aom_som_b2b_b2c start
4. Stop the hybris server and datahub
   ./install.sh -r sap_aom_som_b2b_b2c stop

If so then at which step the build fail?

If you look at the gradle file in /hybris/installer/recipes/sap_aom_som_b2b_b2c/build.gradle, you will see all needed extensions in `extensions` configuration. So your localextensions.xml should definitely not be empty.

Depending on the version of hybris you used, you can have an issue with the recipe (I've experienced that with datahub on 6.1). So you have either to fix the gradle file or to look at it to do all the steps manually.
Basically, you have to set the configuration in local.properties, add the extensions in localextensions.xml and run all the ant commands (and in your case start the datahub server).

Also note that recipes must be only used in a clean hybris platform. (the version right after extracting from the archive).

Comment: Thanks for response. In first step itself I was getting an error. so for now I tried removing the erroneous node from localextension.xml and repeated first step. It worked fine.

Comment: @user3739866 yes you shouldn't have an existing config before running the recipe installer.